# CTRL+SHFT+ENTER Array Formula not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, countif

So my issue is a more complex one, but I have tried with a much simpler formula (with a similar case) and I get the same problem. The array formula I'm using only returns the results for the first value in the array...

FOR EXAMPLE.

in a column I have 5 letters: A, B, C, D, E

and my formula is

```
{=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,{"A","B","C","D"})}
```

which gives me the result: 1       It's only counting the "A" values

when it should be: 4

[image]

Does anyone what can I do instead or why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

No need for CSE, wrap in SUM() or SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,{"A","B","C","D"}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are only a handful of Excel functions that accept arrays and array constants:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-formulas-in-Excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173

> Some of the built-in functions are array formulas, and must be entered as arrays to get the correct results.

I swear I saw a list of which functions support arrays for their parameters, but for the life of me I cannot find that page.

Anyway, it seems that the Criteria parameter is only looking at the first item in your array. If you were to change your formula to the following:

`{=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,{"e","a","b","c"})}`

The result is `0`. This means that the Criteria parameter does not accept array constants (or other arrays).

You can do what Scott did in the other answer or you can continue using Count If, but in another way:

`{=COUNT(IF($B$1:$B$4={"a","b","c","d"},1))}`

It's a little more typing, but it gets the answer you're looking for.

You can also use SUM for the same thing (slightly different from Scott's answer):

`{=SUM(($B$1:$B$4={"a","b","c","d"})*1)}`

Comment: The versions with `COUNT` and `SUM` are a little more problematic than Scott's version with `COUNTIF`. In his version you can substitute the range for any sized range, e.g. a row like `A2:E2` or even a square range like `A1:J10`....but with `COUNT` formula above, for example, it won't work at all with `A1:J10` and would need to change to work with `A2:E2` (semi-colons in place of commas in the array constant)

Comment: @barryhoudini it's only problematic if their requirements change. I didn't realize about the `SUM(COUNTIF())`'s version's ability to handle expanding data, though. Thanks for the tip.